# Rails 3.2 Email Attachments appear as text in Body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, email-attachments

I have an email client in my Rails 3.2 app that stores emails in the database. The content of the email is saved using [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) with the attachments saved using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). These emails are sent using the Mailer that I created, shown below:

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base   
  def messaging_message(msg)
    begin
      Message.transaction do
        @msg = msg

        msg.attached_files.each do |attached_file|
          attachments[attached_file.file_file_name] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/attachments/messaging/messages/#{msg.id}/#{attached_file.id}/#{attached_file.file_file_name}")
        end

        mail_msg = mail(
          to:           Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.to_recipients), # This converts the list of Recipient objects into "emai@address.com; email2@address.com" format
          cc:           Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.cc_recipients),
          bcc:          Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.bcc_recipients),
          from:         msg.access_department.email,
          subject:      msg.subject,
          body:         msg.body,
          content_type: "text/html"
        )

        # Sets the user_name, password and domain based on the FROM address the user selected in the app
        mail_msg.delivery_method.settings.merge!(msg.access_department.mail_settings)
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.error "MODEL: '#{class_name}' - METHOD: '#{method_name}'"
      Rails.logger.error " -> ERROR: #{e}"
      Rails.logger.error "BACKTRACE:"
      Rails.logger.error "#{e.backtrace.join("\n ")}"
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

I then run this action with the following code:

```
msg = Message.find(20)
MessageMailer.messaging_message(m).deliver
```

Without attachments this works like a charm. However, when I have attachments, they appear in the body of the email as a long string of characters, i.e. a text version of the mime type. Here is an example:

> ----==_mimepart_54be256d7d18_13ad78fe74390bc Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per quot antiopam elaboraret cu, ei epicuri
>   perfecto has. Ut utinam discere legimus vis, an quidam habemus
>   menandri nec. Eam dolores suavitate dissentias in, wisi vitae at his.
>   Qui et augue conclusionemque, ut sea doctus impetus inermis. Vitae
>   semper molestiae id mea, est corpora prodesset referrentur ex. In mel
>   diceret expetendis. Mea te impetus vivendum interesset, erroribus
>   referrentur mea ex.
>
> Possit ornatus labores te eos. Per id unum mucius insolens, ne quo
>   elitr ludus nusquam. Amet possit persius eam cu. Pro no nostro
>   nominati. Ut zril persecuti eum, eu ius graece tempor, an agam
>   mediocrem disputationi est.
>
> My Personal Signature
>
> ----==_mimepart_54be256d7d18_13ad78fe74390bc Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=UTF-8; filename=Side_rolling_bulk_vessels_Klein.jpg
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename=Side_rolling_bulk_vessels_Klein.jpg Content-ID:
>   <54be256c7da70_13ad78fe74389af@Theo-Ubuntu-Laptop.mail>
>   /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4RZ1RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMA
>   AAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAEx
>   AAIAAAAbAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAjYdpAAQAAAABAAAApAAAANAAAABIAAAA
>   AQAAAEgAAAABQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTIFdpbmRvd3MAMjAwOTowMzoy
>   NCAxMDo0NDo1OAAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAAB//8AAKACAAQAAAABAAABVKADAAQA
>   AAABAAAB4wAAAAAAAAAGAQMAAwAAAAEABgAAARoABQAAAAEAAAEeARsABQAA
>   AAEAAAEmASgAAwAAAAEAAgAAAgEABAAAAAEAAAEuAgIABAAAAAEAABU/AAAA
>   AAAAAEgAAAABAAAASAAAAAH/2P/gABBKRklGAAECAQBIAEgAAP/tAAxBZG9i
>   ZV9DTQAC/+4ADkFkb2JlAGSAAAAAAf/bAIQADAgICAkIDAkJDBELCgsRFQ8M
>   DA8VGBMTFRMTGBEMDAwMDAwRDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM
>   DAENCwsNDg0QDg4QFA4ODhQUDg4ODh........

I have tried reordering my code, rewriting it in the format shown [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail#sending-an-email) in the [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem, as well as explicitly adding the attachments with their mime type and encoding the myself, yet I still get the same result.

Can anyone please explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue like above.

Just remove the line `content_type: "text/html"` from your code.

Rails will automatically send a multipart email with an attachment, properly nested with the top level being `multipart/mixed` and the first part being a `multipart/alternative` containing the plain text and HTML email messages.

For more info, see [Rails - Sending Emails with Attachments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.18/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments)

Comment: oh man you saved my day. thanks its working fine after removing content_type: "text/csv"

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of searching and trial & error, I managed to find what was wrong with my code.

The problem wasn't in the way that I was adding the attachments, but in the way that I was adding the **body** of the email. An email is structured in the following way (this is very simplistic):

- `multipart/mixed`

  - `multipart/alternative`

    - `text/html`
    - `text/plain`
  - `image/png`
  - `application/pdf`
  - ....

I'm not sure why, but I'm guessing that by adding the `content_type` of the email directly, I was overriding some defaults in the creation of this email. In addition, the `msg.contents` returned HTML.

Since I had a feeling that my issue was with the `content_type`, I tried creating a view for my contents. So I now had the following:

mailers/message_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base   
  def messaging_message(msg)
    begin
      Message.transaction do
        @msg = msg

        msg.attached_files.each do |attached_file|
          attachments[attached_file.file_file_name] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/attachments/messaging/messages/#{msg.id}/#{attached_file.id}/#{attached_file.file_file_name}")
        end

        mail_msg = mail(
          to:       Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.to_recipients), # This converts the list of Recipient objects into "emai@address.com; email2@address.com" format
          cc:       Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.cc_recipients),
          bcc:      Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.bcc_recipients),
          from:     msg.access_department.email,
          subject:  msg.subject
        )

        # Sets the user_name, password and domain based on the FROM address the user selected in the app
        mail_msg.delivery_method.settings.merge!(msg.access_department.mail_settings)
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      Rails.logger.error "MODEL: '#{class_name}' - METHOD: '#{method_name}'"
      Rails.logger.error " -> ERROR: #{e}"
      Rails.logger.error "BACKTRACE:"
      Rails.logger.error "#{e.backtrace.join("\n ")}"
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

app/vies/message_mailer/messaging_message.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{content: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}
  %body
    = @msg.contents.html_safe
```

Now when I ran the following:

```
msg = Message.find(20)
MessageMailer.messaging_message(m).deliver
```

it all worked, and I got an email with downloadable attachments!

What I'm guessing happened is that now I let the [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem deal with the creation of my Email rather than setting content types myself.

Hope this helps others that encounter the same issue, as I found very little help with this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try method below

```html
msg.attached_files.each do |attached_file|
      attachments[attached_file.file_file_name] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/attachments/messaging/messages/#{msg.id}/#{attached_file.id}/#{attached_file.file_file_name}")
end

mail_msg = mail(
          to:       Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.to_recipients), # This converts the list of Recipient objects into "emai@address.com; email2@address.com" format
          cc:       Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.cc_recipients),
          bcc:      Message.convert_to_mail_addresses(msg.bcc_recipients),
          from:     msg.access_department.email,
          subject:  msg.subject
)


mail_msg do | format | 
  format.html { render layout: false }
end
```

And in the mailer view file,
app/vies/message_mailer/messaging_message.html.erb

```
<%= render inline: @html_body.html_safe %>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).